# How to show nonassociativity of the positive rationals under a binary operation defined in terms of max and min?

Tags: binary-operations, associativity

Consider $\mathbb{Q}^+$ with the usual $\leq$ relation and the binary operation $\circ$ defined as:

$$p \circ q = max(p,q) + \frac{1}{2} min(p,q)$$

A book that I'm reading states that the operation $\circ$ is not associative with respect to $\mathbb{Q}^+$, with verification left to the reader. I have tried to verify this by picking random triples $(p,q,r)$ of positive rational numbers as examples, but in each case I end up with the result that $p \circ (q \circ r) = (p \circ q) \circ r$.

For example, take $p=4.5, q=18.1, r=7$:

\begin{align}
4.5 \circ (18.1 \circ 7) &= 4.5 \circ (max(18.1,7) + \frac{1}{2} min(18.1,7))\\
&= 4.5 \circ (18.1 + 3.5)\\
&= 4.5 \circ 21.6\\
&= max(4.5,21.6) + \frac{1}{2} min(4.5,21.6)\\
&= 21.6 + \frac{1}{2} 4.5\\
&= 23.85
\end{align}

and then:
\begin{align}
(4.5 \circ 18.1) \circ 7 &= (max(4.5,18.1) + \frac{1}{2} min(4.5,18.1)) \circ 7\\
&= (18.1 + \frac{1}{2} 4.5) \circ 7\\
&= 20.35 \circ 7\\
&= max(20.35,7) + \frac{1}{2} min(20.35,7)\\
&= 20.35 + \frac{1}{2}7\\
&= 23.85
\end{align}

Am I not picking the right triples of positive rationals for a counterexample, or am I misunderstanding somehow?

Comment: Isn't $\mathbb Z^+$ the set of positive *integers*?

Comment: Yes, sorry, I will edit now. I meant the positive rationals!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select $q<p<p+q/2<r$, for example, $q=2,p=3,r=5$.

We get $(p\circ q)\circ r=r+p/2+q/4$ and $p\circ(q\circ r)=r+p/2+q/2$.

Comment: Thank you! Is there anything special about $\mathbb{Q}^+$ for the nonassociativity of this operation? I'm guessing it would also be nonassociative in $\mathbb{R}^+$?

Comment: @relationalist Since $\Bbb Q^+\subset\Bbb R^+$ this relation is non-associative on the latter or any other superset which contains my counter-examples.

Comment: @relationalist If you are satisfied with my answer, consider accepting it by clicking the tick mark button next to it.

Comment: Done--I'm new to this site, so thanks for letting me know